# Xamarin Android Menu Item does not use App Theme

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I can't figure out how to make the app theme apply to a menu item in the action bar. I have the app theme in a theme xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name ="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
    <!--<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/CustomActionBarTextAppearance</item>-->
  </style>

  <!--<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name ="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
  </style>-->

  <style name="CustomActionBar" parent ="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <!--<item name="android:height">75dp</item>-->
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>-->
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTextAppearance</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomActionBarTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MenuItemTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and in my Actiity class I have this in the OnCreateOptionsMenu

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    //some stuff

    ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

   MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.action_bar, menu);


    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Resource.Menu.action_bar points to this item

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/right_drawer_menu"
      android:title="MENU"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

The title(MENU string) of the inflated Menu item does not use the app theme and I can't get it to change. The activity title however uses the specified theme(CustomActionBarTextAppearance). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

itemTextAppearance works only on sub-items not the top item. To make it work on top menu item the only option I found is

1. to define actionViewClass for menu item
2. style it in OnCreateOptionsMenu
3. Then the problem is how to handle the click. I couldn't pass it to parent (didn't work for me) so the solution is below.
   The only problem with this answer is that menu for some reason opens on the left side but not under the "MENU" where it should be and AFAIK we cannot change it.
   So, I would suggest not to use sub-menu itmes but show some popup sub-menu.

action_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/right_drawer_menu"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Button">

    <menu>
      <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
            android:title="New" />
      <item android:id="@+id/open"
            android:title="Open" />
    </menu>

  </item>
</menu>
```

Activity

```
IMenu myOptionsMenu;
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    //some stuff

    ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.action_bar, menu);
    myOptionsMenu = menu;

    var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.right_drawer_menu);

    var button = item.ActionView as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Text = "MENU";
        button.SetTextColor(Color.Red);
        button.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        button.Click += menuClick;
    }

    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


private void menuClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myOptionsMenu.PerformIdentifierAction(Resource.Id.right_drawer_menu, MenuPerformFlags.None);
    var item = myOptionsMenu.FindItem(Resource.Id.right_drawer_menu);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention. Option to show menu with "OpenOptionsMenu" doesn't work. There are bug created and many discussions about this problem.

Comment: @Oyebisi Any comments?